# jQuery filter to show/hide and append and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple filter to filter elements of the DOM by color, one part of the filter works just fine, where I click the item in the list, but what I am also trying to do is to create a tag of the selected filer with small cross, which is when clicked will reset the filter back to the previous state.

**Filter HTML**

```
<div class="accordion-content">
  <ul id="color-filter">
    <li class="form-checkmark is-selected" data-filter="black" data-filter-type="color"><span class="label"><span class="checkbox black checkmark"></span><span class="radio-text">Black</span></span></li>    
    <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="blue" data-filter-type="color"><span class="label"><span class="checkbox blue"></span><span class="radio-text">Blue</span></span></li>
    <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="brown" data-filter-type="color"><span class="label"><span class="checkbox brown"></span><span class="radio-text">Brown</span></span></li>
    <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="green"  data-filter-type="color"><span class="label"><span class="checkbox green"></span><span class="radio-text">Green</span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Filtes]

**HTML Elements**

```
<div class="grid-23 material-tiles">
  <div class="selected-filters">
     <div class="filter-label">YOUR ACTIVE FILTERS</div>
     <div class="filter-item"><span>Black</span><span class="filter-close"></span></div>
     <div class="filter-item"><span>Blue</span><span class="filter-close"></span></div>
  </div>    
<div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="black">
        <span class="sample-name">Black</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="black">
        <span class="sample-name">Black</span>
</div>    
<div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue">
        <span class="sample-name">Blue</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue">
        <span class="sample-name">Blue</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="brown">
        <span class="sample-name">Brown</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="brown">
        <span class="sample-name">Brown</span>
</div>
</div>
```

The first part `.selected-filters` should show the filters that were selected

[image: Selected Filters]

The rest are just `<div>` with sample colors that should be displayed or hidden, depending on the selection.

So what I am trying to archive is when filter tag is closed to show back hidden color samples and remove class `.checkmark` and `.is-selected` and at the same time close the tag `<div class="filter-item"><span>Black</span><span class="filter-close"></span></div>`
Or if filter is clicked again then do the same as above.

So far my attempts failed as I do not know much about js and jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
    function onGridChangeRequest() {
    var  selected = [];

    $('#color-filter').find('.is-selected').each(function(i, el) {
        selected.push($(this).attr('data-filter'));
    })

    $('.material-tiles').find('.samples').each(function(i, el) {
        if(selected.length) {
            if (selected.indexOf($(el).attr('data-color')) !== -1) {
                $(el).show();
                return;
            }
            $(el).hide();
            return;
        }
        $(el).show();

    })
}

$('#color-filter > li').on('click', function(e) {
    var checkBox = $('.checkbox');
    var filteBlock = '<div class="filter-item"><span>'+ $(this).text() +'</span><span class="filter-close"></span></div>';
    $(this).toggleClass('is-selected');
    $(this).find(checkBox).toggleClass('checkmark');
    $('.selected-filters').css('display','block').append(filteBlock);


    $('.filter-close').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $('#color-filter > li').find(checkBox).removeClass('checkmark');
        $('#color-filter > li').removeClass('is-selected');
        $('.material-tiles').find('.samples').css('display','block');
    });
    onGridChangeRequest();
});
```

[Here is Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm1kpfay/1/)

Comment: Can you please create fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Omi, I have just added fiddle

Comment: now i think your problem is when you remove filter record is not updating right?

Comment: Correct, it just does not do what it is supposed to do. Also, if you click on the colors in the colors column, it will add color tag twice, instead of removing it.

Comment: ok i ll add the answer

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: can you tell me how did we know checkbox is checked

Comment: When you click on any of the colors in the color column the little square appears inside the big square, at this point `.checkmark` is added to `<span class="checkbox blue"></span>`

Comment: that means the checkbox having checkmark class is checked

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#color-filter > li').on('click', function (e) {
            var checkBox = $('.checkbox');
            $(this).toggleClass('is-selected');
            $(this).find(checkBox).toggleClass('checkmark');
            var color = $.trim($(this).text());
            if ($(this).find(checkBox).hasClass('checkmark')) {
                var filteBlock = '<div class="filter-item"><span>' + $(this).text() + '</span><span class="filter-close">X</span></div>';
                $('.selected-filters').show().append(filteBlock);

            } else {
                $(".filter-item span:contains('" + color + "')").parent().remove();
            } 
            
            if($(".selected-filters .filter-item").length<=0){
            $(".selected-filters").hide();
            }
            
            onGridChangeRequest();
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.filter-close', function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            var color = $.trim($(this).siblings('span').text());
            $('#color-filter > li .radio-text:contains("' + color + '")').trigger('click');
            onGridChangeRequest();
        });
        
        
        function onGridChangeRequest() {
    var  selected = [];

    $('#color-filter').find('.is-selected').each(function(i, el) {
        selected.push($(this).attr('data-filter'));
    })

    $('.material-tiles').find('.samples').each(function(i, el) {
        if(selected.length) {
            if (selected.indexOf($(el).attr('data-color')) !== -1) {
                $(el).show();
                return;
            }
            $(el).hide();
            return;
        }
        $(el).show();

    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-13 filter">
  <div class="filters-body">
    <div class="accordion is-open">
      <h3 class="accordion-header">COLOUR<span class="accordion-indicator"></span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <ul id="color-filter">    
            <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="black">
              <span class="label">
                <span class="checkbox black"></span>
                <span class="radio-text">Black</span>
              </span>
            </li>    
            <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="blue">
              <span class="label">
                <span class="checkbox blue"></span>
                <span class="radio-text">Blue</span>
              </span>
            </li>    
            <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="brown">
              <span class="label">
                <span class="checkbox brown"></span>
                <span class="radio-text">Brown</span>
              </span>
            </li>    
            <li class="form-checkmark" data-filter="green">
              <span class="label">
                <span class="checkbox green"></span>
                <span class="radio-text">Green</span>
              </span>
            </li>                   
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-23 material-tiles">
  <div class="selected-filters" style="display:none">
    <div class="filter-label">YOUR ACTIVE FILTERS</div>
  </div>    
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="black">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: #000;">Black</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="black">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: #000;">Black</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: blue;">Blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: blue;">Blue</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="brown">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: brown;">Brown</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="brown">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: brown;">Brown</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="green">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: green;">Green</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="green">
    <span class="sample-name" style="width: 100px; height:100px; display:block; margin-top:5px; background: green;">Green</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm1kpfay/1/) now its working please have a look.

Basically there was two problems:

One is that you are not checked for condition if checkbox is not checked. 
I have just checked for `checkmark` class i.e. `$(this).find(checkBox).hasClass('checkmark')` if this is true then we'll just append the filter nothing else. if it is not true then we ll remove that filter and then called your `onGridChangeRequest()` method which'll filter among samples.

Another one was, you need to do same logic if you removed filter directly. One thing is you are adding filter dynamically so `click()` event directly will not work for close filter because `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so used `$('body').on('click', '.filter-close', function () {}`. Main thing from filter we will get the color name & will trigger manually click event of `li` which has that color, so automatically our radio button click logic will call & you acheive same result.

One of the main selector used here is [contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much it all worked as I expected, one minor problem is that when there is no tags in "Your Active Filters", the `<div class="selected-filters">` should not be visible, meaning it should have `style="display: none"`

Comment: For that you can use `length` e.g. `$(".selected-filters .filter-item").length` this ll give you count of filter if its 0 then hide that. i have updated anser